# remoting - information about the client. c#

Tags: c#, remoting

Is it possible to find out / get some information about the connecting client when using remoting on .net 2.0? I like to know get some information about the connecting client on the server side, so I can act accordingly? This is a small and very local application that Never will have more then max 10 simultaneously connecting/requesting clients.

pass client reference in each function? (or some identifier)? I could do it this way, but I would prefer to just get the information from the request/connecting client. Ip-address or similar would be nice.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the answer I provided for a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527676/identifying-the-client-during-a-net-remoting-invocation):

[Identifying the client during a .NET remoting invocation (Answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527676/identifying-the-client-during-a-net-remoting-invocation/527756#527756)

Answer (score 1):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66363/get-external-ip-address-over-remoting-in-c) might have the answer you're looking for.

I stripped out the parts that probably don't matter to you and left the part that actually grabs the IPAddress.

```
public ServerProcessing ProcessMessage(IServerChannelSinkStack sinkStack, 
    IMessage requestmessage, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, 
    System.IO.Stream requestStream, out IMessage responseMessage, 
    out ITransportHeaders responseHeaders, out System.IO.Stream responseStream)
{
    // Get the IP address and add it to the call context.
    IPAddress ipAddr = (IPAddress)requestHeaders[CommonTransportKeys.IPAddress];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384003/) shows the apparent format of a URI, i.e. the [URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.objref.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the [ObjRef](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.objref%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you get from [RemotingServices.GetObjRefForProxy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.remotingservices.getobjrefforproxy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when you pass it a remote object.  The string between the first two slashes is a per-process GUID, which uniquely identifies the client from the perspective of the local program.

In my case, I just needed some way to identify the client, not its IP address (which wouldn't be valid with a non-TCP channel anyway), so this worked for me.