# Gathering client information (IP address and MAC Address)

Tags: c#

I'am creating a LAN chat application. I already created the client and the server part of the application.

What I want to know is how can my server display the information of the host that are connected to it. For example if there are 5 clients that are connected to the server, I want the server to gather the information of each client like IP address or its MAC address? Can anyone there help with this problem?

Comment: go search a bit on this forum and then ask it, some reading for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950020/remoting-information-about-the-client-c-sharp

Comment: @M.Babcock my clients uses TCP.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you're not working with ASP.NET, in which case you could get at least the IP Address by using the Request object properties.

Some information can be found here:

[Reliable method to get machine's MAC address in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850650/reliable-method-to-get-machines-mac-address-in-c-sharp)

[Identifying the client during a .NET remoting invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527676/identifying-the-client-during-a-net-remoting-invocation/527756#527756)