# Remoting identifying ip address

Tags: c#, remoting, .net-1.1

Is there is any way in Remoting through which we can identify ip address of an incoming request.
Please note I am using .Net Framework 1.1

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66363/get-external-ip-address-over-remoting-in-c-sharp

Comment: I know this is unrelated, but you should *really* look to move off both a: remoting, and b: .NET 1.1. Both are long overdue (ok, *technically* you have another year left of extended-support for 1.1)

Comment: :-) I know this Marc, thanks for Advice